# Palindrome with Recursion

Tags: python, recursion

I'm trying to make a slightly more advanced palindrome as according to the docstring. However I can't get it to work. Am I going it about the right way? This is what I have so far:

```
def pal_length(s: str, n: int) -> bool:


'''Return True iff s has a palindrome of length exactly n.

  >>> pal_length('abclevel', 5)
  True
  >>> pal_length('level', 2)
  False
  '''
  if not s:
      return True
  else:
      index = 0
      while index < len(s):
          if s[index] == s[index+n]:
              return pal_length(s[index+1:index+n-1],n-1)
          index += 1
  return False
```

I'm trying to not use any import modules etc. Just straight recursion.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: @Christan what are you talking about?

Comment: @Christian Please see [this](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your indexing is a bit off. Shouldn't it be

```
index = 0
while index < len(s) - n + 1:
    if s[index] == s[index+n-1]:
        return pal_length(s[index+1:index+n-1], n-2)
    index += 1
return False
```

Comment: Quickly looking at it, it seems that your small fix solved the issue. But why is it -2 instead of -1?

Comment: @Mac: because you strip off _two_ chars when branching to the next recursion `level => eve`.

Comment: thanks for the help! I should've seen that earlier. I'll wait a bit in case anyone is in the process of answering and then I'll accept yours.